# List pushed in navigation view is not rendered

Tags: list, view, navigation, touch, extjs

I am using sencha touch 2.

**My App.js file (summed up)**

```
Ext.application({

launch: function() {

// ...

var list = Ext.create('Ext.List', {
    itemTpl : '<img src="{icon}"/>{title}<br/>{description}',
    store: store,
    listeners: {
    select: function(view, record) {
        var customView = Ext.create(record.get('view'));
        navView.push(customView);
        view.deselectAll();
    }
    }
});

//----------------------------------------------------------------------
var navView = Ext.create('Ext.NavigationView', {
    navigationBar:{
    items: [{
        text:'refresh',
        align: 'right'
    }]
    },
    items: [list]
});

//----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ext.Viewport.add(navView);
}
});
```

When i am loading a view within my navigation view, everything is ok appart when it conains a list.
There is a view with a list in it.
The subpanel is rendered, but not the list view (the list view has been tested and is of course rendering in a different context)

```
Ext.define('ts.views.jobs', {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
layout:'fit',
config:{    
title:'Jobs'
},

initialize: function() {
this.callParent();
var jobsStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'ts.model.job',
    data: [{
    key2: 'key1'
    }, {
    key2:'key2'
    }, 
    {
    key2:'key3'
    }
    ]
}); 

var jobsList = Ext.create('Ext.List', {
    xtype: 'jobsList',
    ui: 'round',
    itemTpl : 'ok{key}',
    store: jobsStore
});

var panel = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
    html: 'Testing'
});

this.add([jobsList,panel]);
}
});
```

**What am i doing wrong ?**
* is it a navigationview bug ?
* am i not initializing properly in my subview ?

Thx for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This was cross posted to the sencha touch forums: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?184492-List-pushed-in-navigation-view-is-not-rendered  and the answer accepted was:

> layout config needs to be within the config object.